Trying to analyze the results from an open-answer question from a survey
I am currently learning how to perform data analysis in R Studio and I am using an SPSS database as an example. Currently I am having problems with the results of an open answer question where people had to write what region they come from. So now I have many cases where the same answer is written slightly different so they are perceived as being different although they refer to the same region.
Example:
x<- c("Bucharest", "ploiesti", "Focsani", 
      "bucharest", "sinaia", "Ploiești", "Sinaia", "BUCHAREST", "Bucharest", "Ploiesti")

table(x)

and the result, if I want to make a table would be:
> table(x)
x
bucharest Bucharest BUCHAREST   Focsani  ploiesti  Ploiesti  Ploiești 
        1         2         1         1         1         1         1 
   sinaia    Sinaia 
        1         1  

I'm not sure if this is the best example as my problem is for a variable/ column from a dataset but I hope that this helps.
I tried using the "str_to_title()" function from the "stringr" package but I get the following error:
Warning message:
In stri_trans_totitle(string, opts_brkiter = stri_opts_brkiter(locale = locale)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing

I want to find a way to make all the answers more uniform (ex: To turn all versions of "Bucharest" into a version with the same spelling that can be recognized as the same answer and do the same for the other answers) and then form a table where I can see how many times does each answer repeat.

x <- data.frame(region = c("Bucharest", "ploiesti", "Focsani", 
      "bucharest", "sinaia", "Ploiești", "Sinaia", "BUCHAREST", "Bucharest", "Ploiesti")) %>% 
  mutate(uniformName = str_to_title(region), 
         uniformName = str_replace(uniformName, 'ș', 's')) %>% 
  group_by(uniformName) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())



Thank you so much for your help! I seem to have a few cases where the name seems identical but they are taken separately. Is there a way to post a ss in the comments to show the problem?

@OctavianSkull What's an "ss"? Have you examined whether there are trailing spaces? Can you provide an example?

By "ss" I meant screenshot. It looks like you provided one in your answer but I can't really find an option to do so myself so I can show the issue. I think trailing spaces could be the issue. I just read that there is a function called "str_trim()" that could help with that so I'll give it a try and see what happens. Thank you again!
